# TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to learn some JS Express and have started building a simple solution to allow me to GET / DELETE / POST / PUT etc. Having problems with the POST router though. Here is the router:-

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const newObject = addToDB(req.body);
    res.status(201).send(newObject);
});
```

and then I have the function

```
const addToDB = (newObject) => {
    newObject.id = `1`;
    objectsArray.push(newObject);
    return newObject;
}
```

ObjectsArray has been defined and works on the GET router but on the POST router, when I test this, I get the error TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined. The code seems almost identical to a code solution from code Academy so I don't understand how I can be getting this error. Using node to run the server and test. Any ideas.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#examples

Comment: You need to use the `body-parser` module. It parses the request data and places it into `req.body` so it is accessible.

Answer (score 2):

From your above code, it seems `req.body` is undefined. You should set up body-parser so as to populate `req.body`. You set it up like so:

1. Install body-parser by running the following in your command line:
   `npm install body-parser`
2. Then before your route add the below lines of code to ensure request parameters are being populated in `req.body`

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Hope this helps.

> Note the above snippet goes in `app.js` or whatever name you call your web server's entry file.